# may i know which C++compilers(online/free) supporting "inheriting constructors" feature in c++0x

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++11

May i know which C++compilers(online/free) supporting "**inheriting constructors**" feature in c++0x

N3290 draft :section 12.9  : Inheriting constructors

I tried with VS10,GCC 4.6.0 ..But i think it is not supporting ..(please confirm it.)

Please tell me which online compilers or Free compilers supporting .. This feature

http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx

I gooogled ..but i didn't get ..the correct info .. help me ?

Comment: You've got GCC6? Did they finally implement C++2x? How's the weather in the future?

Comment: How do you know what you got is not the correct info? Do you happen to know what the correct info is? Why are you asking then?

Comment: Does gcc6 finally fully support variadic templates?

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, may be OP mis-spelled it. `GCC 6 ==> GCC 4.6`.

Comment: @iammilind: Nonsense. OP is clearly a time traveller.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So let's see:

- google didn't find any compiler claiming to implement it;
- overview pages don't list any compiler claiming to implement it;
- clang, Comeau, GCC, and MSVC overview pages don't claim they implement it.

Seems consistent to me!

Maybe you do not like the answer you found, but it appears to be correct!

EDIT: Added clang and Comeau to the list, as suggested by comments.

**NOTE**: At some point in time, compilers will start to implement this. I won't update this answer when they do, so this answer might be out of date by now. *A quick search on 10-feb-2012 didn't reveal any compilers that have implemented this yet, though.*

Comment: Just to be complete the clang site will also list it as not implemented yet. (But delegating it is implemented.) Comeau does not implement it aswell.

Comment: @RedX: I guess no-one really see the point to implement it when there are still eagerly awaited features like *lambdas* :)

Comment: GCC 4.8 will implement it according to their C++11 status page.